# Indent child elements of jqgrid group

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, user-experience

Does anyone know how to indent the text of a child element of a group in jqgrid?

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you can apply a cssClass to the column in the ColModel definition using the "classes" property:

```
colModel: [{ name: 'location', index: 'location', sorttype: "text", classes:"indentMe"}
```

Then you simply need the css defined like something similar to the below:

```
<style type="text/css">
        .indentMe
        {
            padding-left: 40px;
        }
</style>
```

You may run into issues with css order of loading, but if you drop that on your page itself, that usually takes care of it. In one case I had to edit the `.ui-jqgrid tr.jqgrow td` line in **ui.jqgrid.css** and bump out the `padding: 0 2px;` entry there for it to work as expected

Good Luck!

Comment: If you run into issues with css order of loading, just add `!important` and it works.